# Binding errors are still generated for a complex property with FallbackValue

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say we have

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication15.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding MyDataObject.MyNestedProperty, FallbackValue={x:Null}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MyDataObject MyDataObject { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class MyDataObject
{
    public string MyNestedProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is I still receive the binding error event though FallbackValue is set:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'MyNestedProperty' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=MyDataObject.MyNestedProperty; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=MyDataObject.MyNestedProperty; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=MyDataObject.MyNestedProperty; DataItem='MainWindow' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

I know that the problem is `MyDataObject` == null. But, I'd expect `FallbackValue` to suppress binding errors in this case (as it does with simple properties).

In my project we use set DataContext after we create a view so we really need some way to suppress those binding errors as they affect the performance.

Answer (score 1):

> In my project we use set DataContext after we create a view so we really need some way to suppress those binding errors as they affect the performance.

Create the bindings programmatically after you have set the `DataContext` then:

```
DataContext = ...;
textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("MyDataObject.MyNestedProperty") { FallbackValue = null });
```

Neither `FallbackValue` nor any other XAML construct will help you do this.

From a MVVM point of view, it's perfectly fine to create the bindings programmatically in the code-behind of the view. Some MVVM libraries such as for example [ReactiveUI](https://reactiveui.net/) even encourages you do to this: https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/data-binding/

Comment: Was afraid of it. Will think about this option.